# SQL realizando consulta errada

Tags: sql, mariadb

Estou tentando identificar quais produtos do estoque atingiram a capacidade mínima ou estão abaixo dela.

Tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE quantidade_minima <= quantidade
```

E obtenho o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver quantidade é maior que quantidade_minima e ainda sim é avaliado como menor ou igual, o que pode esta causando esta avaliação errada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

acho que a query certa seria:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE quantidade <= quantidade_minima
```